# Eliminar fichero residual de Word de mi proyecto

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo el siguiente código:

```
public function imprimirWord(Juego $j){
    $phpWord=new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
    $phpWord->getSettings()->setThemeFontLang(new Language(Language::ES_ES));
    $section=$phpWord->addSection();

    $text=$section->addText('Juego Nº '.$j->numero.': '.$j->nombre,array('name'=>'Arial','size' => 15,'bold' => true));
    $section->addImage($j->ruta(), array('width'=>400, 'height'=>300, 'align'=>'center'));
    $text=$section->addText("-Materiales requeridos: ".$j->materiales);
    $text=$section->addText("-Agrupación: ".$j->organizacion);
    $text=$section->addText("-Cómo se organiza el juego: ".$j->agrupacion->nombre);
    $text=$section->addText("-Desarrollo del juego: ".$j->desarrollo);
    if($j->observaciones!='*')
        $text=$section->addText("-Reglas y observaciones: ".$j->observaciones);
    if($j->variantes!='*')
        $text=$section->addText("-Variantes del juego: ".$j->variantes);
    $contenidos=$j->enlaces;
    $valor=count($contenidos);
    if($valor){
        $texto="";
        foreach($contenidos as $contenido){
            $texto.=" ".$contenido->contenido->nombre;
            $valor--;
            if($valor>1)
                $texto.=",";
            else if($valor==1)
                $texto.=" y";
            else
                $texto.=".";
        }
        $text=$section->addText("-Contenidos del juego:".$texto);
    }

    $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
    $deciso='Juego Nº '.$j->numero.' - '.$j->nombre.'.docx';
    $objWriter->save($deciso);
    return response()->download(public_path($deciso));
}
```

Este me permite crear un fichero de Word, pero hay un problema: Tambien crea una copia dentro de mi proyecto.
Para arreglarlo, dispongo de este código: `unlink($deciso);`, el cual se encarga de eliminar dicho fichero de word.
Y aquí viene mi problema, que al necesitar usar `return` para que se cree el fíchero, si pongo este código tras la creación del documento, no se ejecutara.
Necesito que el usuario reciba su documento sin necesidad de un return, para así tras que se le genere pueda yo eliminar el documento con un `unlink`.
¿Cómo lo logro?

Edito: Algo que me han sugerido es que guarde el fichero en la carpeta /tmp, ya que esta se va “reiniciando” con el tiempo.
Cuando creo el fichero con save, el proyecto se guarda en public_html. ¿Como hago para que se guarde en la otra carpeta?

Comment: ¿Es necesario generar un fichero? No conozco los detalles de PHP, pero en la mayoría de los sistemas puedes sencillamente pasar el contenido del fichero como respuesta a la petición HTTP directamente.

Comment: @SJuan76 Dices que podria buscar una formar de darle al usuario su fichero word, pero sin tener que generarlo en mi proyecto. La historia entonces es como se logra. $objWriter->save($deciso); es el comando que crea el fichero word en mi proyecto.

Comment: Algo que me han sugerido es que guarde el fichero en la carpeta /tmp, ya que esta se va “reiniciando” con el tiempo.
Cuando creo el fichero con save, el proyecto se guarda en public_html. ¿Como hago para que se guarde en la otra carpeta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya se me ha ocurrido una forma de solucionar esto.
De entrada, he creado lo siguiente en Juego.php:

```
public function ficheto(){
    return 'descargas/Juego Nº '.$this->numero.' - '.$this->nombre.'.docx';
}
```

La historia es que para empezar he creado una carpeta "descargas", donde a partir de ahora almacenare los ficheros Word.
El siguiente paso es hacer este cambio radical:

```
public function imprimirWord(Juego $j){
    $deciso=$j->ficheto();
    if(!file_exists($deciso)){
        $phpWord=new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
        $phpWord->getSettings()->setThemeFontLang(new Language(Language::ES_ES));
        $section=$phpWord->addSection();

        $text=$section->addText('Juego Nº '.$j->numero.': '.$j->nombre, array('name'=>'Arial','size' => 15,'bold' => true));
        $section->addImage($j->ruta(), array('width'=>400, 'height'=>300, 'align'=>'center'));
        $general=array('bold'=>true);

        $text=$section->addText("-Materiales requeridos: ", $general);
        $text=$section->addText($j->materiales);

        $text=$section->addText("-Agrupación: ", $general);
        $text=$section->addText($j->organizacion);

        $text=$section->addText("-Cómo se organiza el juego: ", $general);
        $text=$section->addText($j->agrupacion->nombre);

        $text=$section->addText("-Desarrollo del juego: ", $general);
        $text=$section->addText($j->desarrollo);

        if($j->observaciones!='*'){
            $text=$section->addText("-Reglas y observaciones: ", $general);
            $text=$section->addText($j->observaciones);
        }

        if($j->variantes!='*'){
            $text=$section->addText("-Variantes del juego: ", $general);
            $text=$section->addText($j->variantes);
        }

        $contenidos=$j->enlaces;
        $valor=count($contenidos);
        if($valor){
            $texto="";
            foreach($contenidos as $contenido){
                $texto.=" ".$contenido->contenido->nombre;
                $valor--;
                if($valor>1)
                    $texto.=",";
                else if($valor==1)
                    $texto.=" y";
                else
                    $texto.=".";
            }
            $text=$section->addText("-Contenidos del juego:", $general);
            $text=$section->addText($texto);
        }

        $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
        $objWriter->save($deciso);
    }
    return response()->download(public_path($deciso));
}
```

Esto hara que en caso de que ya se haya creado el fichero, se descargue directamente para no tener que volver a crearlo de nuevo.
Esto es más eficiente para el usuario al darle la posibilidad de que tarde menos tiempo en descargarse, pero me da una serie de pegas.

Hay 2 que he descubierto:

La primera es que cada vez que modifique o elimine el juego, seria recomendable eliminar el fichero, ya que ahora la información de dicho fichero estara obsoleta.

La segunda es que a partir de ahora estoy obligado a que no puedan haber 2 juegos que se llamen igual, ya que eso podria causar que se descargue por error el Word de otro juego. Esto ultimo me va a obligar a hacer cambios en mi base de datos.

¿Alguien se le ocurre otras complicaciones que deba tener en cuenta?

Answer (score 1):

Podes decirle que borre el archivo luego del download con [`deleteFileAfterSend(true)`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#file-downloads)

```
return response()
   ->download($pathToFile, $name, $headers)
   ->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
```

`$pathToFile` es la ruta y nombre del archivo temporal.

`$name` es el nombre de archivo con el que se guardará en la maquina cliente.

`$headers` son headers adicionales que quieras enviar junto al archivo.

Un ejemplo de headers para documento word:

```
$headers = array(
   'Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;'
);
```

Para crear un archivo temporal con nombre único podes usar un md5 del nombre mas microtime, algo así:

```
$tempDoc = md5($deciso . microtime());
```

Y luego al enviarlo le pasas el nombre correcto con los headers para word2007

```
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save($tempDoc);

$headers = array(
   'Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;'
);

return response()
  ->download($tempDoc, $deciso, $headers)
  ->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
```

Comment: Interesante, aunque llega algo tarde.

Comment: quedará para generaciones futuras =P